# Django: create many-to-Many relationship without creating intermediary table

Tags: django, django-models

I have a set of tables that Ive turned into django models. The tables weren't architected very well and  i can't change them, and it is causing problems for this one many to many relationship I'm trying to set up in my code.

Models

```
class Owner(models.Model):    
    owner_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    email = models.TextField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField( blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    owned_apps_whistic = models.ManyToManyField("Applications", through="ApplicationOwnerXRef", related_name="owners_whistic")
    #owned_apps_group = models.ManyToManyField("Applications", through="BusinessUnitOwnerXref", related_name="owners_group")
 

class Applications(models.Model):
    application_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    url = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    service = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_date = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    business_unit_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class BusinessUnitOwnerXref(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    owner_uuid = models.ForeignKey(ApplicationOwner, models.DO_NOTHING, to_field="owner_uuid", db_column = "owner_uuid")
    business_unit_name = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

Owners can own applications by owning the group that owns the application, indicated in the BusinessUnitOwnerXref table.

The Application table and the BusinessUnitOwnerXref both have the business_unit_name column , and can be directly joined

I cant use a foreign key because the BusinessUnitOwnerXref.business_unit_name column isn't unique.

TLDR, Is there a way to create the many-to-many relationship between Applications and Owners, through BusinessUnitOwnerXref, without altering the existing tables or letting django create another table?

Comment: If the `business_unit_name` is not unique, you need to refer to another column that is unique.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sadly there isn't one that is common to both the Application and BusinessUnitOwnerXref tables. That table is the passthrough for sql joins. Im hoping i can make use of it without adding a new table